# Xubuntu 23.04: Firefox icon is not shown on the panel. How to fix it?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, 23.04

I am running Xubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster on the old Dell laptop (2014). Firefox icon is not displayed on the panel (see figure)
[image: Firefox icon]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a launcher shortcut that was created.  Just make sure that you have an icon chosen for it.

Right click on the launcher and choose Properties:

[image]

Click on Edit the currently selected item:

[image]

Click on the Icon box:

[image]

You should be able to search for firefox and select it as the icon for your launcher:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is the solution.